# Approach for finding the limits and intersections of a function given by triple integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Hello I have a problem finding the intersection of a function when I am given a function in $3$D space. I can easily find an intersection of two functions when I have equations with $x$ and $y$ only. But when I have also $z$, I don't know in which order to intersect the equations and because of that I have trouble solving triple integrals without spherical coordinates so I am asking for your help. I have an example with easy equations for the domain but I want to understand the problem in general. So I have this integral $$\iiint_Dxy^2z^3dxdydz$$ with domain : $V=(z=xy,y=x,x=1,z=0)$. So from first look I thought it will be easy to find the limits. I have to intersect $z=xy$ with $y=x$ so I get $z=y^2$. So the only other thing i have is that $x =1$ and $y=x$ and if I try to express x from the equations I get weird results. So I thought $y=x$ is the upper limit for $y$ but I can't find the lower limit for $y$. Also, I cannot even find one limit for $x$. I graphed the function and like it is supposed to be  a straight line for $xy$ that intersects $z^2$ which is a parabola but this doesn't help me. I will be thankful if someone can help me with this.

Comment: The region $V = \{ z = xy, y = x, x = 1, z = 0\}$ doesn't seem to be a volume. Did you mean something like $0 \leq x \leq 1$ and similar inequalities on other variables too?

Comment: @sudeep5221 It's a bounded set. The surface $z=xy$ intersects the plane $z=0$

Comment: Oh my bad. These will be planes. Gotcha!

Comment: In this case, the region can also be defined as $\{ 0 \leq z \leq xy, \ x \leq y \leq 1, \ 0 \leq x \leq 1 \}$. Using these limits, integrate in the order $z,y,x$ to obtain the required result.